# Drag and drop with jquery (a toolbox and a report window)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After a lot of searching I've come here.

I'm trying to use a div as a toolbox item within a toolbox (also a div).  I'm trying to use drag and drop onto a form (another div).  The item appears on the form successfully, however subsequent drops causes the item to appear lower and lower down the page.  It appears as though the div is still floating to the bottom of the previous item.  I'm trying to have the item appear where the mouse pointer is before dropping onto the form.

My code:

```js
var mouseX, mouseY;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$.getJSON('index.php?option=com_report&layout=datajson&format=json', function(result) {
        //    $.each(result.titles, function(i, item) {
                
        //            $('#mogrify_report').append('<br/>' + item);
        //    });
        //});
        $('.mogrify_report_tool').draggable({
            
            revert: 'invalid',
            helper: 'clone',
        });
        $('#mogrify_report').droppable({
            accept: '.mogrify_report_tool',
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                
                var droppable = $(this);
                var draggable = ui.draggable;
                

                if(!draggable.hasClass('.mogrify_report_component')) {
                    var cloned = draggable.clone();
                    cloned.draggable();
                    
                    cloned.detach().prependTo(droppable);

                    
                    cloned.addClass('.mogrify_report_component');

                    cloned.css('top', mouseY - droppable.offset().top);
                    cloned.css('left', mouseX - droppable.offset().left);
                }
            }
        });
        $(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
            //$('#mogrify_report').text( 'pageX:' + event.pageX + ', pageY: ' + event.pageY);
            mouseX = event.pageX;
            mouseY = event.pageY;
        });
    });
```

```css
#mogrify_reportbackground {
    background: #8888ff;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#mogrify_padding {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#table_row {
    display: table-row;
    width: auto;
    clear: both;
}

#table_col_toolbox {
    float: left;
    display: table-column;
    width: 150px;
}

#table_col_report {
    float: left;
    display: table-column;
    width: 900px;
}

#table_col_padding {
    float: left;
    display: table-column;
    width: 150px;
}

#mogrify_toolbox {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    
}



#mogrify_tool_label {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.mogrify_report_tool {
    position: fixed;
}

.mogrify_report_component {
   
}

#mogrify_report {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 800px;
    height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mogrify_reportbackground">
 <div id="mogrify_padding">
     <div id="table_row">
      <div id="table_col_toolbox">
          <div id="mogrify_toolbox">
           <div id="mogrify_tool_label" class="mogrify_report_tool">
            Label
           </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="table_col_report">
                <div id="mogrify_report">
                
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="table_col_padding">
            
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make `mogrify_report_tool`'s position `absolute` in drop event. and make `mogrify_report`' position relative in your css.

```js
var mouseX, mouseY;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$.getJSON('index.php?option=com_report&layout=datajson&format=json', function(result) {
        //    $.each(result.titles, function(i, item) {
                
        //            $('#mogrify_report').append('<br/>' + item);
        //    });
        //});
        $('.mogrify_report_tool').draggable({
            
            revert: 'invalid',
            helper: 'clone',
        });
        $('#mogrify_report').droppable({
            accept: '.mogrify_report_tool',
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                
                var droppable = $(this);
                var draggable = ui.draggable;
                

                if(!draggable.hasClass('.mogrify_report_component')) {
                    var cloned = draggable.clone();
                    cloned.draggable();
                    
                    cloned.detach().prependTo(droppable);

                    
                    cloned.addClass('.mogrify_report_component');
  cloned.css('position','absolute');
                    cloned.css('top', mouseY - droppable.offset().top);
                    cloned.css('left', mouseX - droppable.offset().left-25);
                }
            }
        });
        $(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
            //$('#mogrify_report').text( 'pageX:' + event.pageX + ', pageY: ' + event.pageY);
            mouseX = event.pageX;
            mouseY = event.pageY;
        });
    });
```

```css
#mogrify_report {
position:relative;
}
#mogrify_reportbackground {
    background: #8888ff;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#mogrify_padding {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#table_row {
    display: table-row;
    width: auto;
    clear: both;
}

#table_col_toolbox {
    float: left;
    display: table-column;
    width: 150px;
}

#table_col_report {
    float: left;
    display: table-column;
    width: 900px;
}

#table_col_padding {
    float: left;
    display: table-column;
    width: 150px;
}

#mogrify_toolbox {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    
}



#mogrify_tool_label {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.mogrify_report_tool {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:50;
}

.mogrify_report_component {
   
}

#mogrify_report {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 800px;
    height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="mogrify_reportbackground">
 <div id="mogrify_padding">
     <div id="table_row">
      <div id="table_col_toolbox">
          <div id="mogrify_toolbox">
           <div id="mogrify_tool_label" class="mogrify_report_tool">
            Label
           </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="table_col_report">
                <div id="mogrify_report">
                
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="table_col_padding">
            
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```